# How do I backup a wallet in monero-wallet-cli?

Tags: monero-wallet-cli, backup

Which files are relevant to an individual wallet's data?

Comment: agreed with the note that .keys file is relevant for restoring, but it's probably better to back-up all the wallet files, so other info (wallet cache, tx keys, address history etc.) is kept as well

Comment: @JollyMort If your comment is referring to answer http://monero.stackexchange.com/a/2066/11 can you move this comment there since this question is being closed?

Comment: aye, gonna comment on the answer, because there's really no reason to back-up **only** the .keys file if you're backing up files anyway. the cache is usually 50mb which is *nothing*