# How can someone verify funds in a XMR wallet usint public viewkey?

Tags: monero-wallet-cli, viewkey, multisig

I know that to create a `view only wallet` you have the following option using the `secret view key`:

> ./monero-wallet-cli --generate-from-view-key wallet-name
>
> Standard address:
>   4jkshetduseokd...
>
> View key:
>   ffgksijdmniod...

Someone with your XMR wallet will be able to see the funds you have in you wallet.

If I share the XMR wallet and the `public view key`, what could anyone do with that information and how can it be used (which are the steps https://xmr.llcoins.net/checktx.html)?

Thank you :).

Answer (score 3):

A view only wallet only allows seeing incoming transactions.

https://src.getmonero.org/resources/user-guides/view_only.html

> A view-only wallet can only see which incoming transactions belong to
>   you. It can not spend any of your Monero, in fact it can't even see
>   outgoing transactions from this wallet. This makes view-only wallets
>   particularly interesting for
>
> - Developers writing libraries to validate payments End users validating
> - incoming transactions to cold wallets

To check a transaction on the blockchain (like with your [linked](https://xmr.llcoins.net/checktx.html) service), you need either the *transaction private key* or the *wallet private view key*.

To be clear, you cannot track transactions on the blockchain with only a wallets *public* view key.

Comment: Also see: https://monero.stackexchange.com/questions/2053/view-key-spend-key-paper-key-seed-is-there-a-short-presentation-of-vocabul

Comment: Thanks for the answer. So the public view key is "useless". I know this is used for the wallet to receive transactions. Can someone do anything with the _public_ view key, or is this a Monero blockchain only thing? If I hand over the public view key, what can you do with it? Anything? 
Thank you for the answer of the private key and link, it's pretty useful. :)

Comment: A sender uses the receivers public spend and view keys when creating a transaction (specially creating the stealth address). So public (view and spend) keys are not "useless".